# How to unbind ctrl enter in vim?

Tags: vim

So I use [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) and I have it bound to ctrl m:

```
nnoremap <C-m> :UndotreeToggle<CR>
```

But for some reason, when I press ctrl enter, it also toggles undotree.

And then when I try to unbind ctrl enter like below, it **still** toggles undotree.

```
nnoremap <C-CR> <Nop>
```

So question is, how on earth do I make it ctrl enter not toggle undotree?

Comment: be sure to map it to nop *after* including the plugin

Comment: Yes I put it as the last line in my vimrc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Vim's point of view, `<CR>` and `<C-CR>` are indistinguishable. Since `<C-m>` and `<CR>` are two representations of the same key, pressing `<C-CR>` is effectively the same as pressing `<C-m>`.

See if `:help modifyOtherKeys` helps.

Comment: Hm I don't get how `<C-m>` and `<CR>` are the same key though...

Comment: See [this table](https://www.windmill.co.uk/ascii-control-codes.html): `<C-m>` is `<CR>`, `<C-i>` is `<Tab>`, etc.